# Usage of performSeguewithIdentifier Function in Dynamic Values Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can list datas in tableview. When I choose a row and trying to pass another view controller with showing specific data related to my pressed cell, It couldn't make it. 
I didn't able to store data "selectedMeal" variable in prepareforsegue function, it always return [ ].
I think, my main problem is selecting the cell and sending to this cell to prepare for segue function. Perhaps, it has a problem in DispatchQueue.main.async function.

*When I try to pass to static data, it works great.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark;

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoOrderDetail", sender: self) 
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "gotoOrderDetail") {
        let DestViewController : OrderDetailListViewController = segue.destination as! OrderDetailListViewController
        let selectedMeal = selectedCells.map { (index: Int) -> SavedMeal in
            return savedMeal[index]
        }
        DestViewController.mealarray = selectedMeal
    }
}
```

Comment: why you are using  DispatchQueue.main.async ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if (segue.identifier == "gotoOrderDetail") {
    let DestViewController : OrderDetailListViewController = segue.destination as! OrderDetailListViewController
    let path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()! // get the selected indexPath
    DestViewController.mealarray = savedMeal[path.row]
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Sender parameter

you can you like this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoOrderDetail", sender: indexPath)
```

and then in prepare(for segue: sender?)

```
if (segue.identifier == "gotoOrderDetail") {
    let DestViewController : OrderDetailListViewController = segue.destination as! OrderDetailListViewController
    let index = sender as! Int
    DestViewController.mealarray = savedMeal[index]
}
```

p/s: you do not need to use dispatch queue in this case